# How to check URL status code in bulk without flooding requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a requirement to check, on an ongoing basis, the status code returned by many URLs. This can be up to 50,000 on the same domain.

I am concerned that by doing this, I risk flooding the site(s) with requests, and impacting performance, which cannot happen.

My current approach to this is to use `requests.head` in order to minimise the size of the response, however I'm unsure as to what additional context I need to be aware of:

- Is there a best practice for rate limiting requests?
- How is this best balanced against execution time?
- Is this enough to ensure that there is no negative impact as a result of running this across a specific domain?

I've looked for similar topics but can't seem to find this, so apologies if this is solved elsewhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal best practice for rate limiting requests to web servers. All web requests which hit a web server are going to affect the performance of that server to some degree.

The number of requests that a specific web server can handle is entirely down to the factors such as the web framework, hardware and complexity of code within the API method. If you take a look at the [TechEmpower benchmarks](https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#test=plaintext) for a simple `{"message":"Hello, World!"}` response you'll see that this can vary dramatically.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an attempt to make sure the server doesnt blacklist me thinking the requests are all coming from the same place if that is one of your intentions as well. It still floods the server but by trying to deceive making it think the requests are not coming from the same place. There are times when I also switch between VPNs to have different IPs.

This is a snippet of using a fake user agent:

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
ua1 = UserAgent()
randomHeader = {'User-Agent':str(ua1.random)}
page = requests.get(restListLink, randomHeader)
```

If putting a delay between requests is not a concern for you, then you can also try to add a random delay mechanism between requests. For the delay, you can check  the sleep function!

```
import time
time.sleep(0.100)
```

Comment: @samg86 asks "Is this enough to ensure that there is no negative impact...". Passing a different user-agent in each request is only an attempt to circumvent the web server's defenses. Additionally, 10 requests per second may well overwhelm the server and we cannot give a universally safe number.

Comment: I have mentioned that in my answer: 'It still floods the server but by..'

Comment: 'we cannot give a universally safe number', elaborated on this by introducing sleep mechanism if time is not a constraint

Comment: limiting to 10 requests per second might be fine for most servers. However, one particular server might not be able to cope with that load or indeed that load may trigger some kind of defense. Changing the user-agent may not be sufficient to sidestep that defense, as the server may look at other characteristics of the request such as the originating IP address. We are getting into the world of DDOS mitigation techniques here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/73948/troy-hunt has a good article on how he implemented automatic blocking of IP addresses based on the frequency of requests to his HIBP API. His threshold is one request every 1.5 seconds. https://www.troyhunt.com/azure-functions-in-practice/